# .getboolean() NoOptionError

Tags: python, configparser

I was trying to read a boolean value using config parser, It finds the section fine but it fails finding the option for some reason.

```
configparser.NoOptionError: No option 'firsttime' in section: 'DEFAULT'
```

In the INI i have:

```
[DEFAULT]
"firsttime" = "true"
```

And in my main folder i have:

```
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
print(config.getboolean('DEFAULT', 'firsttime'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`ConfigParser()` constructs the configuration parsing object, but doesn't read in any configuration file. To do that you have to invoke its read method, e.g. `config.read(<your_config_file>)`. So if your config file was named `example.ini`, your code would look like:

```py
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('example.ini')
print(config.getboolean('DEFAULT', 'firsttime'))
```

As a side note putting quotations in the init file will screw up the parsing of it. So you'll want your init file to look like:

```ini
[DEFAULT]
firsttime = true
```